# Double-hitting the same breakpoint in VSCode 1.84.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Not specific to any workspace, I have to press 'Continue' twice to get the variables in the debug panel updated.
For instance, to go past the line on the image [image] I have to press 'Continue' twice, while the expected behavior is to do it once.

Comment: Does it happen for every breakpoint, or just some? What happens if you step over and then continue?

Comment: It happens for some of the breakpoints. If I step over and continue the execution is the same: some breakpoints behave normally, while to get over others one needs to press 'continue' twice